# Flutter lazy loaded (and/or pagable) datatable/grid

Tags: flutter

Are there any options for a fully featured grid control like you'd see in basically any other UI framework like Angular/React/WinForms/WPF etc?

Specifically, I want to have it do virtual scroll (lazy loading) and or paging where it pulls the page on demand from the async data source. Despite its description the PaginatedDataTable isn't really a paginated data table because it still requires the data to be loaded per row and isn't async so you have to load all of the data ahead of time.

Nothing else seems to fit the bill.

Bonus features of sorting by column on demand, filtering etc. like you'd see in DevExpress, Telerik and any other number of grid controls on the market for other platforms.

Suggestions?

Comment: use `ListView Widget`

Comment: Listview is missing basically all of the characteristics of a grid control and has issues with virtualization of large data on scroll from what I can tell?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [responsive_grid_list](https://pub.dev/packages/responsive_grid_list) in which docs says:

> A Flutter plugin to create responsive grid lists using ListView.builder(), SliverList with a SliverChildBuilderDelegate or any other list.
>
> The provided Widgets essentially work like a Flutter Wrap Widget but
> they are more performant with large lists because of the internal use
> of ListView.builder() functions.

And helps with your 'lazy loading' issue.